# Loss of precision while working with double

Tags: c++, floating-point

Could we work with big numbers up to 10^308.
How can I calculate the 11^105 using just double?

> The answer of (11^105) is: 
>   22193813979407164354224423199022080924541468040973950575246733562521125229836087036788826138225193142654907051

Is it possible to get the correct result of 11^105?
As I know double can handle 10^308 which is much bigger than 11^105.
I know that this code is wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double n, p, x;
    cin >> n >> p;
    //scanf("%lf %lf", &n,&p);
    x = exp(log((double)n)*p);
    //printf("%lf\n", x);
    cout  << x <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not using `double`, take a look to https://gmplib.org/

Comment: The simple answer is no.  This number isn't representable in a `double`.

Comment: You can obtain a `double` close to the real 11^105 with `pow(11.0, 105.0)`. Using `exp()` and `log()` as you are doing is a large source of inaccuracy. Note that you will never obtain the real 11^105 this way, as this number is not exactly representable as a `double`.

Comment: 11^105 = [22193813979407164354224423199022080924541468040973950575246733562521125229836087036788826138225193142654907051](http://codepad.org/2WeoUAyI)

Comment: `11^<whatever>` ends in `1`

Comment: @MohitJain yes, I have made mistake. I have copied and pasted the result of 25^25. Btw, I have it calculated using Python.

Comment: Agree with Pascal Cuoq, with my version of libm, exp(log(11)*105) is more than 100 ulp away from nearest double to 11^105. A decent pow implementation shall do better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double` usually has 11bit for exp (-1022~1023 normalized), 52bit for fact and 1bit for sign. Thus 11^105 cannot be represented accurately.

For more explanation, see [IEEE 754 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)

Comment: So if 52 bit stored for mantissa, then the number of digits in mantissa can be calculated:  x = 52 * log(2) / log(10); // x = 15.6536 So, 15 digits can be stored without lost of precision?

Comment: @UnhandledException No. The decimal number 0.1 has only one significant digit, but it cannot be stored without loss of precision, because binary is not decimal.

Comment: @UnhandledException You are partially correct. With `double`, you get 15 digits of useful value. However, 0.1 can't be represented accurately in binary, just as 1/3 can't be represented accurately in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

[Double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) can hold very large results, but not high precision. In constrast to fixed point numbers, double is floating point real number. This means, for the same accuracy double can shift the radix to handle different range of number and thus you see high range.

For your purpose, you need some home cooked big num library, or you can find one readily available and written by someone else.

BTW [my home cooked recipe](http://codepad.org/qeZBlRuB) gives different answer for 11<sup>105</sup>
Confirmed with this [haskell code](http://codepad.org/2WeoUAyI)